# Can we keyframe hair particle brownian motion?

Tags: animation, particles

Is there a good reason to be unable to keyframe a hair particle system's brownian motion? Or is it a bug? I can't change this value, because its keyframe at another frame prevents it from being changed.

[image]

Comment: The same seem to be true for all of the particle system settings.

Comment: correction: _hair_ particle system settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is a bug. When the type is set to hair most keyed settings are snapping back to the keyed value which prevents new keyframes being added or adjusted from the properties panels. This is not hair only settings, physics, field weights and force field weights are also affected, while render settings do work properly.

For a workaround you can add keyframes and adjust settings in the graph editor once a value has a keyframe.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid my question wasn't clear.. Since the value is keyframe'd on another frame, I'm unable to change the value to keyframe on a different frame. In other words, the first keyframe seems to lock the value across the whole scene.

Comment: Is somebody going to file a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/), or is everyone keen on just leaving it broken? *Or...* has a bug report already been filed and just not addressed yet? Let's bring this to developers' attention if it hasn't been already.

Comment: I have just created a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T47080) for this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes we can change the keyframe, Just active Regrow option in particle setting.